# ExpressJS error: Object #<Object> has no method 'resetMaxAge'

Tags: node.js, session, express

Here's my ExpressJS controller:

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res) {
      Company.findOne({_id: user.company_id}, function(err, company) {
        if(err) {
          response = {
            status: 'error',
            error: err
          }
        } else if(!company) {
          response = {
            status: 'error',
            error: 'User not identified with a company'
          }
        } else {
          req.session = user;
          response = {
            status: 'ok',
            user: user,
            api_key: company.api_key
          }
          return res.json(response);
        }
      });
    }
}
```

In my express config, I have:

```
app.use(express.session({
  secret: config.sessionSecret,
  store: new mongoStore({
    db: db.connection.db,
    collection: config.sessionCollection
  })
}));
```

The error I get is: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'resetMaxAge'`

Comment: Can you update with the complete error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the express config to:

```
 app.use(express.session({
      "secret" : config.sessionSecret,
      key: 'PutYourKey',
      cookie: {secure: false, maxAge: 300000},
      store: new mongoStore
      ({
         db: db.connection.db,
         collection: config.sessionCollection
      })
  }));
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain why this could solve the issue? As far as I have seen while debugging this error is that the object req.session does not implement the resetMaxAge parameter. My express session configuration also includes the cookie maxAge and I don't see why adding a key or secure false should define that method.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is quite some time ago I would guess that `req.session = user;` is the real root of the problem...